# How to retrieve a list of Memory Cache keys in .NET Core?

Tags: caching, .net-core, memory

How to list all the register keys from Memory Cache in the .NET Core web application?

Comment: Just `foreach`? It has a `GetEnumerator()` (which is what `foreach` uses): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.getenumerator?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Runtime_Caching_MemoryCache_GetEnumerator (but see the note marked "important")

Answer (score 1):

I found. I share it to help you.

```
var cacheEntriesCollectionDefinition = typeof(MemoryCache).GetProperty("EntriesCollection", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        var cacheEntriesCollection = cacheEntriesCollectionDefinition.GetValue(_cache) as dynamic;
        List<ICacheEntry> cacheCollectionValues = new List<ICacheEntry>();

        foreach (var cacheItem in cacheEntriesCollection)
        {
            ICacheEntry cacheItemValue = cacheItem.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(cacheItem, null);
            cacheCollectionValues.Add(cacheItemValue);
        }
```